# Can i use mysql databases from some other websites for my site?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Can u tell me, can i use database from this server `www.serversfree.com` for my own website?
I googled but couldn't find anything ..
Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you are allowing in your database to access from outside. If you are behind firewall, you need to set up portforward. But i do not recommend this.

Instead to directly access your database from outside your server, let's write an API, use API key and security tokens to perform actions on your DB.

Comment: I am making school website, and hosting provider allows me to crate only 1 database ...

Comment: And how is this relevant to your question? Your question was, can you access your database from another server. Answer is yes. I do not mentioned, you need to set up another database.

Comment: Well, because my provider doesn't allows me to create multiple databases i wanted to try to use database from other server

Comment: Please read my answer again. In your sql databse, check the `mysql` database `user` table. There are a colum `host`. You can set up a user, what can access your database from a specified IP, or rang of IPs. for example outsideuser@192.168.1.% see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html

As i mentioned, this is not so secure, and need more configuration, if you are behind firewall. What i sad is to write an api. See my next comment.

Comment: So, when you says from `www.serversfree.com/yourdir/test.php` you need to call an api what pointed to `www.yourserver/api/?action=getUser&name=Joe`. And then you need to write a script, what is get the user with name `Joe` from your database, and show it as a result. And then, in your `www.serversfree.com/yourdir/test.php` need to process the result.

Comment: Why do you need more than one database? Usually even in one database you can add as many tables as you need with different names, thereby adding all stuff you need to only one database. Unless that database has a size limit you are hitting against...